# Keras Bidirectional LSTM returns two outputs (fwd + backward), which step maps to which row in the output tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Using the following Keras bidirectional LSTM:

```
x_forward, x_backward = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
  layer=tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True),
  merge_mode=None  # return separate forward and backward outputs
)
```

`x_foraward` and `x_backward` are now tensors of shape `[batch_size, seq_length, 128]`. In `x_forward` I presume that `x_forward[:, 0, :]` maps to the output for sequence step `0`, and so on.

I'm unclear about `x_backward`. Does `x_backward[:, 0, :]` map to the first sequence step or the last sequence step?